# C I/O: Handling keyboard input on the Windows console

Tags: c, windows, io, cross-platform, keyboard-input

I am creating an interactive console application that should run on both Linux and Windows operating systems. Within the program, there are prompts which ask for keyboard input from `stdin`. At each prompt, the user can only enter specific ASCII characters, as well as a specific number of characters. The prompts also have special behavior if the `<Escape>` or `<Enter>` keys are pressed; `<Enter>` submits the prompt to be evaluated by the internal program state, and `<Escape>` triggers a command which exits the program without requiring the prompt to be submitted. At the moment, these prompts only work on Linux because I do not know how to implement them for Windows.

The input prompt is currently implemented via two functions: the generic handler function `prompt_user_input`, and the platform-layer function `platform_console_read_key`, which only has a working Linux implementation at the moment--not Windows.

`platform_console_read_key` works like this:

1. Immediately read up to six bytes from `stdin` into a buffer (multiple bytes allows for parsing ANSI escape codes for non-ASCII keys).
2. If the first byte read *is not* an escape sequence indicator, the first byte is returned as a regular ASCII character.
3. If the first byte *is* an escape sequence indicator, bytes 2-6 of the buffer are parsed.

   1. If the rest of the buffer is empty, then the character is standalone, so do step 2.
   2. If there is something in the latter part of the buffer, then it is actually an escape sequence. Attempt to parse and return it as an "extended key code" (which is just a `#define` for an integer > 255).
   3. If there is something in the latter part of the buffer, and it is an escape code which is not handled by the function, return the special value `0`.
4. If there is any kind of critical I/O error, return the special value `KEY_COUNT`.

The reason I read the characters like this is because I handle each key code returned by `platform_console_read_key` separately in `prompt_user_input` to determine how the program should proceed. `prompt_user_input` works like this:

1. Take an argument which is the maximum number of characters which may be input.
2. Read keys via `platform_console_read_key` in an infinite loop.
3. If last key matches `<Enter>` or `<Escape>`, break from the loop.
4. Otherwise, see if it is a valid key using a `filter_user_input` predicate.

   1. If it is valid, add it to an input buffer, as long as the number of the characters written to the buffer does *not* exceed that allowed by the function argument. Also print it to the screen (i.e. "echo" functionality).
   2. If max writes reached, or key is invalid, continue (i.e. goto step 2).

My question is how I would implement `platform_console_read_key` for the Windows platform layer. How can I immediately read 6 bytes of keyboard input at the Windows terminal? Also, how do I determine how these 6 bytes will be formatted, so that I can map the Windows key codes to the function's return values such that the behavior of the function matches that of the Linux version?

Below is the working Linux code, where the platform layer includes `<termios.h>` and `<unistd.h>`. I omitted some irrelevant code, as well as added some `printf` statements for clarity and ease of testing. Note also that in `prompt_user_input` there are references to a global `( *state ).in`, which is the input buffer; assume it is always big enough for the supplied `char_count`.

```
bool
prompt_user_input
(   const u8 char_count
)
{
    printf ( "Type your response: " );

    // Clear any previous user input.
    memset ( ( *state ).in , 0 , sizeof ( ( *state ).in ) );

    KEY key;
    u8 indx = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        key = platform_console_read_key ();
        
        if ( key == KEY_COUNT )
        {
            // ERROR
            return false;
        }
        
        // Submit response? Y/N
        if ( key == KEY_ENTER )
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        // Quit signal? Y/N
        if ( key == KEY_ESCAPE )
        {
            //...
            return true;
        }

        // Handle backspace.
        if ( key == KEY_BACKSPACE )
        {
            if ( !indx )
            {
                continue;
            }
            indx -= 1;
            ( *state ).in[ indx ] = 0;
        }

        // Response too long? Y/N
        else if ( indx >= char_count )
        {
            indx = char_count;
            continue;
        }

        // Invalid keycode? Y/N
        else if ( !filter_user_input ( key ) )
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Write to input buffer.
        else
        {
            ( *state ).in[ indx ] = key;
            indx += 1;
        }

        // Render the character.
        printf ( "%s"
               , ( key == KEY_BACKSPACE ) ? "\b \b"
                                          : ( char[] ){ key , 0 }
               );
    }
}

KEY
platform_console_read_key
( void )
{
    KEY key = KEY_COUNT;

    // Configure terminal for non-canonical input.
    struct termios tty;
    struct termios tty_;
    tcgetattr ( STDIN_FILENO , &tty );
    tty_ = tty;
    tty_.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr ( STDIN_FILENO , TCSANOW , &tty_ );
    fflush ( stdout ); // In case echo functionality desired.
    
    // Read the key from the input stream.
    char in[ 6 ]; // Reserve up to six bytes to handle special keys.
    memset ( in , 0 , sizeof ( in ) );
    i32 result = read ( STDIN_FILENO , in , sizeof ( in ) );
    
    // I/O error.
    if ( result < 0 )
    {
        key = KEY_COUNT;
        goto platform_console_read_key_end;
    }

    // End of transmission (I/O error).
    if (   in[ 0 ] == 4
        || in[ 1 ] == 4
        || in[ 2 ] == 4
        || in[ 3 ] == 4
        || in[ 4 ] == 4
        || in[ 5 ] == 4
        )
    {
        key = KEY_COUNT;
        goto platform_console_read_key_end;
    }

    // ANSI escape sequence.
    if ( *in == '\033' )
    {
        // Standalone keycode.
        if ( !in[ 1 ] )
        {
            key = KEY_ESCAPE;
            goto platform_console_read_key_end;
        }

        // Composite keycode.
        else
        {
            if ( in[ 1 ] == '[' )
            {
                // ...
            }
            else
            {
                key = 0;
            }
            goto platform_console_read_key_end;
        }
    }

    // Standalone ASCII character.
    else
    {
        // Backspace key is mapped to ASCII 'delete' (for some reason).
        key = ( *in == KEY_DELETE ) ? KEY_BACKSPACE : *in;
        goto platform_console_read_key_end;
    }

    // Reset terminal to canonical input mode.
    platform_console_read_key_end:
        tcsetattr ( STDIN_FILENO , TCSANOW , &tty );
        fflush ( stdout ); // In case echo functionality desired.
        return key;
}
```

**EDIT**

Solved, thanks to the accepted answer. Here is the minimal Windows implementation of `platform_read_console_key` that keeps the behavior of `prompt_user_input` the same. It uses the `<conio.h>` header.

```
KEY
platform_console_read_key
( void )
{
    i32 getch;

    getch = _getch ();

    // Error.
    if ( getch < 0 )
    {
        return KEY_COUNT;
    }

    // Standalone ASCII keycode.
    if ( getch != 0 && getch != 224 && getch < 0x100 )
    {
        return newline ( getch ) ? KEY_ENTER
                                 : ( getch == '\033' ) ? KEY_ESCAPE
                                                       : getch
                                                       ;
    }

    // Extended keycode.
    getch = _getch ();
    switch ( getch )
    {
        default: return 0;  // Unknown keycode.
    }
}
```

Comment: On Windows you can read console input directly with `conio.h` and `getch()` or `getche()`. Function keys and cursor control keys return 2 values. If the first is  `0` or `224` there is a another value to be read from another call. There is also `kbhit()` which you can poll before committing to the blocking function `getch()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane :  There is no standard conio.h on Windows.  It is not a Windows API.  It existed in MS-DOS compilers and even then Microsoft's library of that name differed significantly from Borland's.  There is a "clone" of the Borland API I think included with MinGW/GCC, but it is a wrapper around the Win32 API console API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions.  Where `kbhit()` for example would be synthesized from `PeekConsoleInput()`.

Comment: @Clifford `conio.h` is part of MS  Visual C.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I stand corrected. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/console-and-port-i-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution user `Weather Vane` hinted at, and that I've used for years.  Running this code will also allow you to discover and hence define many more F-keys -- you know, `F1`, `F2`, also `arrow keys`, and the like.

NOTE:  you want that add of 256 to `_getch()` for the extended keys in `GetKey()`.  This places extended key values outside the range of common keys like `A thru Z`....noting that `F10` by itself would only be value `68` -- and *that* matches with the key value for `SHIFT + 'D'`.  No good, see?

This code will also work for `CTRL` + key combos.  Also works for `ALT` key combos within limits. `ALT` key combos get a little hairy because `ALT+TAB key`, for example, switches between applications in MS Windows.  Hence, when your app starts competing with the OS for keystroke actions, behavior might become undefined.  And -- per experience -- you can add 100s of lines of code to remedy these things but only increase performance and scope nominally.

Code was compiled in Visual Studio and tested on Win10 before posting to SO.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define KEY_ESCAPE  27
#define KEY_BACKSPACE 8  
#define KEY_ENTER 13
#define KEY_F10  324


/*---------------------------------------------

    GetKey()

    Thanks John Wagner
*---------------------------------------------*/
int GetKey(void) 
{
    int c = _getch();
    if(c ==0 || c == 224)
        c = 256 + _getch(); /* If extended key (like F10), add 256. */
    return c;
}

int main () 
{
    int key;

    printf("Hit a key -- ESC key quits\n");

    do{
        key = GetKey();

        switch(key)
        {
            case KEY_ENTER:
                printf("ENTER key detected.\n");
            break;

            case KEY_BACKSPACE:
                printf("BACKSPACE key detected.\n");
            break;

            case KEY_F10:
                printf("MENU(F10) key detected.\n");
            break;

            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                printf("User says yes!\n");
            break;

            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                printf("User says No!\n");
            break;

            default:
                printf("Key value: %d\n", key);
            break;
        }

    }while (key != KEY_ESCAPE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Edited my post to add the solution, and I accepted the answer.